# How to re-initialize my bean

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, mockito

I have a bean in my applicationContext-test.xml that I use for mocking an external search engine. This way, when I run tests, any time my application code refers to this search engine, I know that I am using my mock engine instead of the real one.

A problem I am facing is that I want this engine to behave differently in different scenarios. For example, when I call `getDocuments()`, I usually want it to return documents. But sometimes I want it to throw an exception to make sure that my application code is handling the exception appropriately.

I can achieve this by referencing the bean in my test code and changing some stubs, but then I have to change the stubs back to what they were so that my other tests will also pass. This seems like bad practice for many reasons, so I'm seeking alternatives.

One alternative I considered was to reinitialize the bean completely. The bean is initialized from the applicationContext-test.xml with a static factory method. What I want to do is:

1. Reference the bean from my test code to change some of its stubs
2. Run the test using these new stubs
3. At the end of this test, reinitialize the bean using the static factory method specified in applicationContext-test.xml

I tried something like this:

```
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            new String[] { "applicationContext-test.xml" });
    Factory factory = appContext.getBean(Factory.class);
    factory = EngineMocks.createMockEngineFactory();
```

But this does not do the trick. Any tests that are run after this will still fail. It seems that my new `factory` variable contains the `Factory` that I want and behaves accordingly, but when the bean is referenced elsewhere, `getDocuments()` still throws the exception that was stubbed in previously. Clearly, my re-initialization only affected the local variable and not the bean itself.

Can someone tell me how I can accomplish my goal?

**Update**

While I appreciate suggestions as to how to write better tests and better mocks, my goal is to reinitialize a bean. I believe there is value in learning how to do this whether it fits my use case or not (I believe it does fit my use case, but I'm having a hard time convincing some of my critics here).

The only answers that will get any up votes or green ticks from me are those which suggest how I can reinitialize my bean.

Comment: My answer would a bit depend how you currently create test-doubles (e.g. mocks, stubs)? Is it hand-crafted or are you using something like easymock or mockito?

Comment: My mocks are created using Mockito and they are setup through an applicationContext. In other words, I do not make mocks for every test that I write, but rather, my application code refers to an @Resource so that when I'm running tests, I load my application context, and every piece of application code that refers to that bean is now using the mocked version instead of the real one.

Answer (score 1):

You should define the cases when you want a result and the cases when you want an exception. They should be differentiated by input parameters to the method. Otherwise it is not a good test. So, for a given set of parameters the output should be predictable.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. These are indeed two different test cases, but the application code that they call into uses the same bean definition for my Factory. I don't wish to manually inject into this bean via a long chain of setters.

Comment: Seems to me he's saying you should be able to provide input that causes the exception to be thrown, instead of using a stub.

Comment: @AHungerArtist: that doesn't make much sense. This search engine is an external jar. I can't change the way it works. There are no values I can pass into getDocuments() that would predictably cause it to throw an exception, so it wouldn't make sense to have a specific value that I'd pass into the mock to cause this behavior, would it?

Comment: @Samo - how do you then expect an exception, if there is no way to predictably expect it? Sorry, I don't see the full picture.

Comment: The point is not to simulate the scenario that causes the exception. The point is to ensure that the exception is handled properly. If my engine throws an exception, I want to make sure that the service that calls this engine eats it and returns an empty list. So I just want to cause the exception, I don't care how. If I were testing a different layer, I could pass parameters into getDocumentsInRange(int, int) that would cause an exception. But I'm testing a layer above my engine to make sure it eats the exception, so I can't control which params get passed into the method.

Answer (score 0):

How about injecting different implementations of the search engine? Just create more beans representing the different mocks of the search engine.

- one test class is initialized with one mock and another test class with another mock; this, of course, means you'll have more test classes for a certain class that you are testing (not that good/clean)

or...

- inject more mocks (of the search engine) in 1 testing class. some testing methods (from that testing class) use one mock, other testing methods use another mock

Comment: @Belun: Your second suggestion doesn't work because the code that refers to my bean is application code, not test code. It's the test's responsibility to load the context that defines this bean. Your first suggestion would only be possible if I had multiple test application contexts. And even if I did this, which sounds like bad practice, I wouldn't be able to run my other tests, since they'd be using the bean that throws an exception. As you suggested, I'd have to have multiple test classes for these.

Comment: @Samo: something does not sound right. so far i see three beans for the search engine and 2 application xmls. the real implementation is one and is located in the application xml for production. the other 2 beans are one that returns some fixed values (a stub) and one that throws some exception in a specific case; these last two are both in the second application xml (that is for testing). what's wrong with my picture ?

Comment: @Belun: What's wrong with your picture is that one piece of application code cannot refer to two different beans from the same context. As I said, my bean is *not* loaded from test code, it's referenced in application code. For example, my test calls into class A. Class A references bean X from an application context. I have no setters to change this bean, nor do I want any. So bean X takes whatever definition is found in the current application context. Does this make more sense?

Comment: @Samo create, in your test class, two beans for class A (the class under testing). one bean has injected a mock, while the other bean another mock. they are 2 different beans, that happen to be of same type (class A) and that are used in different test methods

Comment: @Belun: I'm not sure how I'm being unclear here. The Beans *are not referenced within my test code!* They are referenced in application code, which is called by my test code. Referencing a bean in my test code does no good at all. Class A references the bean. Actually, it's more like, the test calls class A, which calls class B, which calls class C, which references the bean. I have no setters for the bean. I want no setters for the bean. If I had any intention of doing it this way I would not have posted this question. I don't want some super long chain of setters just so I can test my code.

Comment: @Belun: sorry to seem frustrated but I've mentioned several times that the bean is not referenced in my test code and that I'm not going to create a long chain of setters just to inject a bean all the way down to a class that uses it, especially since this is only useful for testing purposes. I want a way to reinitialize my bean, hence the title of the question.

Comment: @Samo but you have contructor injection, right (in class A; for a class X, which is the mock) ?

Comment: @Belun: I'm not currently using constructor injection, but even if I did, imagine this scenario: From my test class, I create mock X. I instantiate class A, passing mock X as a constructor arg. A instantiates B with X. B instantiates C with X. Then C uses X. I don't care for this pattern of passing an object to a class whose only use for it is to pass it to another class, and another class, ad nauseum. *I want to reinitialize my bean!*

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
factory = EngineMocks.createMockEngineFactory();
```

do:

```
factory.callMethodThatChangesTheStateOfThisObjectSuchThatItIsSuitableForYourTest(withOptionalParameters);
```

Also, if you are using Spring Integration Testing, make sure to annotate your method with @DirtiesContext so it won't affect the next test.